# Linux amdgpu - switch pixel format (YCbCr444 from RGB 4:4:4)

Tags: linux, amd-radeon, rgb

Is it possible to change the pixel format in any AMD driver on linux (currently Ubuntu Mate)?
I am wondering if the amdgpu/amdgpu-pro/radeonsi have this capability?
I have the pc with AMD A10 Micro-6700T connected to a Panasonic TV, and it defaults to RGB full range, but this crushes the blacks too much.

Thanks!